# SGD with momentum in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, sgd

In Caffe, the SGD solver has a momentum parameter ([link](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/solver.html)). In TensorFlow, I see that `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer` does not have an explicit momentum parameter. However, I can see that there is `tf.train.MomentumOptimizer` optimizer. Is it the equivalent of Caffe SGD with momentum optimizer?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes it is. `tf.train.MomentumOptimizer` = SGD + momentum

Comment: Thanks @nessuno. The tensorflow documentation is a little inadequate, I'd say.

Comment: if you look at formula of SGD+momentum in Caffe (http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/solver.html) and in TF(https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/train/MomentumOptimizer?hl=en) you can see these are little different.

Answer (score 1):

[tf.keras.optimizers.SGD](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/SGD) has a `momentum` parameter. Applying a Nesterov momentum is also possible by using `nesterov=True`.

Comment: Just to  clarify tf.keras.optimizers.SGD has no minimize method for tensorflow 1.6. It is suitable for passing as an argument to keras sequential model.fit. However, tf.train.MomentumOptimizer can be used.